# Understanding the logic and code to create a graph in python from a .txt file using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the state of the world right now, I have been working with the Matplotlib python package. I am at the point now where I want to make a program that is a bit more interactive.

I am trying to make a program where the first three lines of a .txt file are: 1. X coordinates 2. Y coordinates 3. user's preferred style. (example blue dotted line).

I am having difficulty understanding the logic behind doing this. I am just trying to begin the whole program and get started.
Am I correct when my thought process is...
open the file and gather the values from each line and place them in a list:

```
with open(argv[1]) as file:
    lines = list(file)
    x_components = list(map(int, lines[0].split()))
    y_components = list(map(int, lines[1].split()))
    line_type = lines[2]

    plt.plot(x_components, y_components, "".join(line_type))
    plt.show()
```

The .txt file will look like so:

> 1 2 3
>
> 2 4 6
>
> --rd

(With no blank line in between)
**Note: the grouping of 3 lines may repeat for many graphs so I believe ill need to wrap into a loop.***

I have made edits to the code by using help from below.

When I call plt.plot() I get an unrecognized character in format string error. Is it because of the .join()?

Thanks

Comment: You talk about _three lines_ but then split every line, i.e. using "columns"?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `while True` as the outermost loop; it'd probably also be a good idea to just keep a list named `lines` and a dictionary for each element with `x`, `y` and `color` instead (be aware - a line usually need two coordinates for a style to be applicable - otherwise you'll have conflicting styles between two lines, depending on meaning)

Comment: @OcasoProtal See edits. I made changes

Comment: So it is in fact the first row x, the second row y and the third row style? Then you are still wrong to assign x and y from the same line. Hint: Read the lines all at once (`f.readlines()` or `list(f)`) and use the first line of that list for x and the second for y and so on ;) Or maybe better change  the file format so that each line contains `x y style`?

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like this (let's call it `data.txt`):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
--rd
```

And your code looks like this:

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        coordinates = line.split(" ")
        x = coordinates[0]
        y = coordinates[1]
```

This will not do what you want. It will also throw an `IndexError` exception.

Here's what happens the way your code is written now (the for-loop will have three iterations because there are three lines in the file):

1. Start with the first line "1 2 3\n" (remember, the trailing newline
   is part of the line as well).
2. Take the current line and split it on spaces only, this yields the
   list `["1", "2", "3\n"]`, assign it to `coordinates`.
3. Assign the first string from this list to `x`. `x` now equals `"1"`.
4. Assign the second string from this list to `y`. `y` now equals `"2"`.
5. Now the second iteration of the for-loop starts, `line` is now `"4 5
   6\n"`.
6. Take the current line and split it on spaces only, this yields the
   list `["4", "5", "6\n"]`, assign it to `coordinates`.
7. Assign the first string from this list to `x`. `x` now equals `"4"`.
8. Assign the second string from this list to `y`. `y` now equals
   `"5"`.
9. Now the third iteration of the for-loop starts. `line` is now
   `"--rd"`.
10. Take the current line and split it on spaces only, this yields the
     list `["--rd"]`, assign it to `coordinates`.
11. Assign the first string from this list to `x`. `x` now equals
     `"--rd"`.
12. Assign the second string from this list to `y`. The list only has
     one element, so Python raises an `IndexError` exception.

So, the problems as I see them are:

- You are not capturing all the values from your lines, and the ones
  you do capture you assign incorrectly. To make it worse, you replace
  the contents of `x` and `y` after each iteration, making all previous
  work useless.
- Assuming you fix the above, you'll need to strip the trailing newline
  from each line. You'll also want to convert the individual numbers
  into integers, since they start out being strings.
- The third line of your file needs to be treated differently than the
  first two lines, since it doesn't contain coordinate data.

Here are the necessary changes I would make:

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    x_components = list(map(int, lines[0].split()))
    y_components = list(map(int, lines[1].split()))
    line_type = lines[2]

    print(f"X-Components: {x_components}")
    print(f"Y-Components: {y_components}")
    print(f"Line Type: {line_type}")
```

Output:

```
X-Components: [1, 2, 3]
Y-Components: [4, 5, 6]
Line Type: --rd
>>>
```

EDIT - With this new information, I've updated the code:

```
...

plot_lines = []

with open("data.txt") as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
    current_lines = lines[i:i+3]
    assert len(current_lines) == 3
    x_components = list(map(int, current_lines[0].split()))
    y_components = list(map(int, current_lines[1].split()))
    line_type = current_lines[2]
    plot_lines.append((x_components, y_components, line_type))

for plot_line in plot_lines:
    plt.plot(*plot_line)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for the deep dive into the example. It really helps me understand. I find the logic/syntax quite a bit more difficult since I'm more used to java. If I wanted to create a graph using matplotlib, would I essentially just get rid of the print and then plot the points?

Comment: I think you can shorten `lines = file.read().splitlines()` to `lines=list(file)`

Comment: @Ocaso Protal Yes, you could do that. However, then you would have to explicitly strip the trailing newlines.

Comment: @user10987432 Please stop editing your questions. Better ask a new question and even better: Learn Python and learn to debug your code.